# Is it possible to bind a list of objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        OtherClass = new List<OtherClass>();
    }

    public List<OtherClass> OtherClass { get; set; }
}
```

OtherClass contains:

```
public class OtherClass 
{
    public OtherClass ()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the following xaml `MyView`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Framework:MyClass}">
   <StackPanel>
      <Label FontSize="20" Content="{Binding Path=OtherClass.Name}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

in `MyWindow` referencing `MyView`:

```
<TabItem Header="My Class">
   <Views:MyView DataContext="{Binding Path=MyClass}" />
</TabItem>
```

I have seen other examples of binding [nested properties](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74b57273-025d-4f23-bb62-6c9bf064e8cf/binding-controls-to-nested-properties?forum=wpf) which suggest that `Binding Path` this way (ie, `OtherClass.Name`) works fine for a single object. However, I am binding a list of objects rather than a single object (in my example, a list of `OtherClass`).

Is it possible to bind a list of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create `DataTemplate` for `MyClass` then you need to use some form of `ItemsControl` to display `OtherClass` list property

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Framework:MyClass}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding OtherClass}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

also `OtherClass.Name` must be a **public property** and not private as it is at the moment

```
public class OtherClass 
{
    public OtherClass ()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

`DisplayMemberPath` is the easiest way to display single property but if you want to display more then one property from `OtherClass` class, or change how it's formatted then you need to define `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` instead and tell `ItemsControl` how to display each item

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding OtherClass}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <!-- more properties that you want to display -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: `Name` property is public...simply forgot it. Question edited.

Comment: @edmastermind29 assumed that but wrote just to be sure. Did you try this answer? What do you want achieve?

Comment: Yes, and the result is no different than what I had before. What I had before was only the type displaying (the `List<OtherClass>`) rather than its values (or a displayed list of its values).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to display and how `MyView` looks like. Assuming that context is instance of `MyClass` this `ItemsControl` should display `OtherClass` list property showing `Name` from each item. Did you try you use `ItemsControl` directly without `DataTemplate`?

Comment: Yes, and I get `All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.` I assume I have something else going on because what you explained to me is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: This means you create some resource wrong or you put in wrong place. This error tells you that if you put something in `Resources` it must have either `x:Key` or `DataType` for `DataTemplate` or `TargetType` for `Style`

Comment: Okay, I reapplied your suggestion, but instead of using a `ItemsControl`, I am using a `ListBox` in a different part of the code (the part I originally applied your suggestion was within a `ContentControl`, if that is of any relevance) and the values are displaying. Unfortunately, I have more than one object (other than `Name`) that I am trying to display, and it doesn't like multiple `ListBox`es or multiple `DataTemplate`s. Any ideas for thought?

Comment: So you want to display more then `Name` for each item? Correct?

Comment: Right. If I have, for example, a `Value`, `Description`, etc. along with `Name` (not shown above), that I would like to display also.

Comment: Check my edit. Also `ItemsControl` is base for all controls that display list of something. It's just repeater without selection which repeats some template for each item and puts it on a `Panel` of your choice. `ListBox` is inherited from `ItemsControl` and adds selection capabilities.

Comment: Wow. I'm going to use a `Label` instead of a `TextBox` and a `WrapPanel` instead of a `StackPanel` as I am trying to display text horizontally, but the sentiment remains. I know the other answers alluded to your edit, but thanks for going above and beyond!

Answer (score 2):

What you'll likely want to do here is make a ItemsControl, where each item of your OtherClass list will be prepresented by one item. Your ItemTemplate will dictate what each item in that list is to display, in your case the ItemTemplate will contain a Label which is bound to  the Name property. See below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding OtherClass}" DataType="{x:Type Framework:MyClass}"> 
    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

(See a more complete example [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/))

Comment: I follow your example, but get a compiler error that states, `All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.` Any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding to a "list" of objects, the list must be bound to a control that has an `ItemsSource` property. These types of controls are able to bind to collections so that the inner `DataContext` of the control is the list's type. In your case, if you bind to the OtherClass property (the list), the `DataContext` scope will be of Type 'OtherClass' where you can then bind to its properties explicitly.

As others have mentioned, you can bind to an ItemsControl, but can also bind to a ListBox, ListView, DataGrid, TreeView, etc.

```
<!-- Using ItemsControl -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding OtherClass}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
              <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
          </DataTemplate.Resources>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

<!-- Using ListBox-->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OtherClass}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
              </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Along with another answer, I get the following compiler error that states, `All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.` Any insight on this?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a Dictionary rather than a List. Based on the above code you posted, it should work. Is there other code you forget to include?

Comment: I do not know where I am using a `Dictionary`. I am using an `ObservableCollection` to display the data, but I am using a `List` as portrayed above.